# Minimum version for syscall nanosleep

Tags: linux-kernel, syscalls

Which is the minimum version of the linux-kernel implementing the system call **nanosleep**? (`sys_nanosleep`)

Comment: It was added in the late 1990s (in ncurses since [February 1998](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t980207)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was added in the late 1990s (in ncurses since [February 1998](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t980207)).  Mailing list comments by David Dawes a year earlier said at that point it was only available in Solaris.

According to [Linux IO mini HOWTO](http://home.isr.uc.pt/~rui/str/Linux-IO-mini-HOWTO.pdf) (December 1997), it was available in the 2.0.x kernels, and was added after the previous version of the HOWTO on March 30, 1997.  I found a French translation of the manual page dated [April 1997](http://www.linux-france.org/article/man-fr/man2/nanosleep-2.html).

From that, it seems it was added in April 1997, which would be 2.0.30 (see [Linux Kernel Version History: 2.0 series kernels](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/docs/history/2.0.html) ).